# Updating an indexed column with NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, indexing, informix

I have a dups index on a DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION column named TouchTime, which I use as a timestamp to locate the most recently inserted or updated row for the current workday. I recently added this column to a table with ~800K rows. An average of 7,000 rows are updated, and 300 rows are inserted each workday. Before users begin inserting or updating rows on the following workday, I update the timestamp column to NULL for all rows in the table which had the previous workday's timestamp.

What effect does it have on the index entry when nullfying the ~7,300 rows which had timestamps?.. Do their leaf locations in the index file remain in the same place?.. When users start adding and updating the workday's rows, will queries using the index automatically bypass rows with null timestamp values?

Comment: Your description sounds like Oracle.  You should tag your question with the database you are actually using.

Comment: I'm looking for feedback for the tagged db's, as this is probably handled differently on these servers

Answer (score 0):

If several of the rows of a timestamp column that is indexed  is set to null the position of the rows in the index table will be moved. SQL Server keeps all indexes in a Btree Plus which keeps all index trees balanced and of equal depth at all times.

Comment: wow, then the cost of re-positioning the leaf node eveytime the indexed column is set to NULL must be very expensive!

Comment: Moving individual pointers to rows is not such an expensive operation compared to a page split which can cause other page splits.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you will have to rebuild your index. This update to NULL is a very unpleasant action for an Oracle database.

Comment: I could understand rebuilding the index if the column being updated to NULL were a primary key, but its not, so why would I have to rebuild index when i'm only nullifying ~7,300 out of the ~800K rows?.. Do NULLS on indexed columns stale the index?

Comment: In Oracle it does not matter if it is a primary key or not. The index just gets messed up with empty leaf nodes since NULL values are not part of the index. In Oracle this makes me avoid NULL in data as much as possible so that at least my query plans are a bit more reliable.

Comment: There are situations when the absence of a value is useful, and sometimes even necessary, especially with temporal values.

Comment: @FrankComputerAtYmailDotCom : I agree with that, Oracle however disagrees in there index model.

Comment: Okay, its good to know, as Oracle 10g is one of the db's I regularly work with, Informix 11.70 is the other.